# How do I use pdfminer.pdffont to extract font size and name as library

Tags: python, pdfminer

**I wish to extract the font of every word and its size in pdfminer**
this is code to extract the layout of pdf using pdfminer 
so to extract pdffont what should I do
don't tell me use the command line i wish to use that in my code

```
def read_pdf_miner(fileObj):
    """
    This function takes the file object, read the file content and store it into a dictionary for processing

    :param fileObj: File object for reading the file
    :return: None
    """
    file_pointer = open(fileObj,'rb')

    parser = PDFParser(file_pointer)

    document = PDFDocument(parser)

    if not document.is_extractable:
        raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed


    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

    device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)

    laparams = LAParams()

    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    page_num = 1
    id = 0
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

        layout = device.get_result()
        for lt_obj in layout:
            if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                text_dict[id] = lt_obj.get_text()
                text_prop_dict[id] = lt_obj
                id += 1
        page_dict[page_num]=text_prop_dict.copy()
        text_prop_dict.clear()
        page_num += 1
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: yes i figure it. thanks

Comment: then post the answer!